# Any way to detect if EntityFramework Core is run inside a tool?

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Is there any way to detect if my application is being run through `dotnet ef *` or the PowerShell alternatives?

I'm creating a multi-tenant ASP.NET Core app with Entity Framework Core and I have logic to decide which connection string should be used, but should not be run if I'm creating migrations or updating a database through the command line. I cannot rely on checking for the existance of an `HttpContext` because I use my `DbContext` during configuration as well, nor can I use additional command line arguments or environment variables.

EDIT: Found a way to see if a connection string has already been configured, it's not ideal but I can use it to help with my particular use case:

```
optionsBuilder.Options.Extensions
    .OfType<RelationalOptionsExtension>()
    .FirstOrDefault()?.ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a type that implements `IDbContextFactory<T>` in your `DbContext` (or startup) project, the tools will call this instead of trying get your `DbContext` from services or instantiate it directly.

Comment: I tried IDbContextFactory before but ended up not using it because it doesn't support dependency injection. I'd need to make all the necessary service and configuration dependencies statically accessible, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Treat it like another `Main` where you can't inject services. Build you service provider by calling `Startup.ConfigureServices()` or factor out another method that both can call.

Comment: Perfect! Made an alternative constructor for `Startup` without `IHostingEnvironment`, then I just called `ConfigureServices` with a `new ServiceCollection`.

Comment: Now, in EF3, it name is IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<T>